# apache2 adding "Options FollowSymLinks" cause 403

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

The following lines event to an empty folder cause a 403 error when accessing that folder. why?

```
<Directory "/path/to/server_root_dir/emty_folder">
    Options FollowSymLinks 
</Directory>
```

i want to create a folder that contains symlinks to other files.

Comment: Is it a rights issue?

Comment: @SPRBRN i don't think so the folder has all posible permisions

Comment: Does the symlink itself have proper rights? All subfolders?

Comment: @SPRBRN ok i changed some things in sites-available/000-default.conf about passwords and it works now . i'm not quite sure why but it does